# Using MapsStruct in kotlin to mapping to openApi data class objects

Tags: kotlin, openapi, mapstruct

I try to use mapstruct in my kotlin project

this is object generated in openApi

```
data class PaymentMethodResponse(

    @get:JsonProperty("id") val id: java.util.UUID? = null,

)
```

When i try to use mapper

```
@Mapper(injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)
interface PaymentMethodMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "paymentMethodId", target = "id")
    fun mapToDto(paymentMethod: PaymentMethod): PaymentMethodResponse
```

it's throwing exception

```
/payment-service/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/main/com/xxx/payment/mapper/PaymentMethodMapper.java:14: error: Property "attributes" has no write accessor in PaymentMethodResponse.
    public abstract com.screwfix.payment.api.model.PaymentMethodResponse mapToDto(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
```

Is there any way to use MapStruct on top of openApi data class?

I've searched for configuration for openApi but it didn't worked also.

Answer (score 0):

Add Setter Method:

In Kotlin, properties are often defined using val or var, which automatically generates getter methods. However, for MapStruct to work, you need to ensure that there's also a setter method available. If the property in your target class does not have a setter (if it's defined as val without a custom setter), MapStruct won't be able to write the value to it.

For example, if you have a property "id" in your target class, make sure it's defined with a **var** and has a corresponding setter method. If you cannot modify the target class, consider using a DTO or a custom mapper method to handle this situation.

Example

```
data class GetImportResponseBodyCache(
@JsonProperty("import_id") @Id var importId: UUID?,
@JsonProperty("dynamic_rules") var dynamicRules: List<String>?,
) {
    constructor() : this(null, null)
}
```